# How to remount a drive without root?

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to allow a user script to `remount` a drive as "ro" or "rw".

By using the `user` option in the fstab, I can successfully mount and unmount the drive as a user but the `-o remount,rw` fails.

Is it not possible for the user to use the `remount` option?!?

`/etc/fstab` reads...

```
UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad /mnt/nasbackup auto rw,user,noexec 0 2
```

but...

```
john@johnbox /mnt> mount UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad
john@johnbox /mnt> mount | grep nvme
/dev/nvme0n1 on /mnt/nasbackup type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,stripe=4,user=john)
john@johnbox /mnt> mount -o remount,ro UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad
mount: /mnt/nasbackup: must be superuser to use mount.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
john@johnbox /mnt [32]> umount UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad
john@johnbox /mnt>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be possible for security reasons. In case an admin sets it to rw or ro specifically, users shouldn't be able to mess with the options. If the user is physically present, they can do SysRq+U but that affects everything. What you can do is put that user's processes in a user and filesystem namespace, where they can only do rw to ro without affecting others.

Comment: @DanielT "Security reasons" does not explain it as a user can `umount` and re-`mount` with different options, but they cannot use the `remount` option itself.  I'm more inclined to think this is an oversight on behalf of the developer?

Comment: I agree now. The responsible code is at https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/27eec306df02e2235788833423f6dd994a96f76c/sys-utils/mount.c#L716 . `mount` is not only refusing the `remount,rw`, but rather completely refusing the `-o`. Looking at it, it would take a refactor to securely support unprivileged `-o` at all, but send a PR if you're interested. As a workaround, you can write two 1-line C programs that are suid and wrap an exec call to `mount -o remount,ro UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad` and the `rw` variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [architectural limitation](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/27eec306df02e2235788833423f6dd994a96f76c/sys-utils/mount.c#L716) of `mount`. As a workaround you can use C to write some suid wrappers. Shell scripts won't work because Bash refuses to keep suid.

1. `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. Paste the following into a `remountro.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
 if (setuid(0) != 0) abort();
 puts("Will remount nasbackup as ro");
 execl("/bin/mount", "mount", "-o", "remount,ro", "UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad", NULL);
 abort();
}
```

3. Paste the following into a `remountrw.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
 if (setuid(0) != 0) abort();
 puts("Will remount nasbackup as rw");
 execl("/bin/mount", "mount", "-o", "remount,rw", "UUID=789f-4b3a-b0b2-c05955d7c5ad", NULL);
 abort();
}
```

4. Run `make remountrw remountro`
5. Run in a root shell:

```bash
chown root:root remountrw remountro
chmod 4755 remountrw remountro # 4 = suid
mv -t /usr/local/bin remountrw remountro
```

6. Now any user can run `remountro` or `remountrw` to fix those exact two commands

You still need the `user` part in `/etc/fstab` so the non-remount commands keep working like before. Alternatively, you can edit `/etc/sudoers`, but it's more complicated to ensure that the parameter restriction rules you write for `sudo` remain secure.